# Why did millis() function sped up one loop and slowed down another one?

Tags: arduino

so I'm making a infinity mirror box with LEDs and I've been stuck on this problem for a few days. I have two buttons and one switch on the box. The switch changes the mode from one to three. First mode just makes it so that LEDs are always on, second mode makes the LEDs slowly turn on and off repeatedly like waves and the third mode makes the LEDs pulsate like a heart. I made three while loops for the modes. Everything worked fine until I added millis() function to the third loop. I checked the code a hundred times it should be working like it supposed to but for some reason after adding millis() function LEDs while in the second mode started blinking very fast but it should be quite slow and the opposite happened in the third mode. The pulses should be quick but for some reason they are slow. When I use serial monitor it looks like everything works correctly, but when I turn the LEDs on weird stuff happens. Sorry for my bad English and the long code but I really need help :DDD.

```
int modePin = 7;
int LEDPin = 11;
int lowPin = 2;
int highPin = 4;
int mode = 2;
int mButtonState = 0;
int mOldButtonState = 0;
int hButtonState = 0;
int hOldButtonState = 0;
int lButtonState = 0;
int lOldButtonState = 0;
float brightness = 255;
float waveLightSpeed = 1;
int pulseLightSpeed = 7;
int intervals = 500;
unsigned long prevTime = 0;





void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(modePin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(highPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(lowPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  chechkForMode();

  while(mode == 1){

    brightness = 255;
    analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);

    chechkForMode();
  }



  while(mode == 2){

    while(brightness > 10  and mode == 2){
      
      analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
      brightness = brightness - waveLightSpeed;
      
      chechkForMode();
      repeat();
    }

    while(brightness < 240 and mode == 2){
      
      analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
      brightness = brightness + waveLightSpeed;
      
      chechkForMode();
      repeat();
    }

    chechkForMode();
  }



  while(mode == 3){

    brightness = 255;
    analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
    repeat();
    unsigned long currentTime = millis();



    if (currentTime - prevTime > intervals){

        while(brightness > 10  and mode == 3){
        
        analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
        brightness = brightness - pulseLightSpeed;
        chechkForMode();
        repeat();
      }

      while(brightness < 240 and mode == 3){
      
        analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
        brightness = brightness + pulseLightSpeed;
        chechkForMode();
        repeat();
      }

      while(brightness > 10  and mode == 3){
        
        analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
        brightness = brightness - pulseLightSpeed;
        chechkForMode();
        repeat();
      }

     while(brightness < 240 and mode == 3){
      
        analogWrite(LEDPin, brightness);
        brightness = brightness + pulseLightSpeed;
        chechkForMode();
        repeat();
      }
      unsigned long currentTime = millis();
      prevTime = currentTime;
    }

    chechkForMode();
  }

}







void chechkForMode() {
  mButtonState = digitalRead(modePin);
  
  if (mButtonState != mOldButtonState) {
    
    if (mButtonState == LOW) {

      mode++;
      if (mode >= 4) {
        mode = 1;
      }    
    }
    if (mButtonState == HIGH) {

      mode++;
      if (mode >= 4) {
        mode = 1;
      }    
    }
  }
  mOldButtonState = mButtonState;
  Serial.print(mode);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(brightness);
}



void repeat(){
  lButtonState = digitalRead(lowPin);
  hButtonState = digitalRead(highPin);
  
  if (lButtonState != lOldButtonState) {
    
    if (lButtonState == LOW) {
      
      intervals = intervals - 100;

      waveLightSpeed = waveLightSpeed - 0.2;

        if(waveLightSpeed < 0.2){
          waveLightSpeed = 0.2;
        }
      
        if(intervals < 100){
          intervals = 100;

    }
 
  }
  
  lOldButtonState = lButtonState;
}


if (hButtonState != hOldButtonState) {
    
    if (hButtonState == LOW) {
      
       intervals = intervals + 100;

       waveLightSpeed = waveLightSpeed + 0.2;

        if(waveLightSpeed > 3){
          waveLightSpeed = 3;
        }
       
        if(intervals > 5000){
          intervals = 5000;

    }
 
  }
  
  hOldButtonState = hButtonState;
}

}
```

Comment: Side comment: It looks like `mode++;` is being executed for both `LOW` and `HIGH` button states

Comment: Oh no it should be like that because I'm not using a button. I don't know what they are called but they are like levers. Every time I switch it I want it to change the mode. So when switch it, it stays in that position. Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: but as far as I can see, your `mButtonState` is always LOW or HIGH, so you will _always_ be changing mode

Comment: I was planning to make two modes only so I put a switch like that so that if it's HIGH then there would be one mode and if it's low than it's the second mode. But later I decided to make three modes but the switch was already in place so I made the mode change with every switch. If I would want to change it I'd have to flick the lever (switch) two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `unsigned long` at the end of the third while loop.

You are creating a NEW, LOCAL variable `unsigned long currentTime = millis();` at the end of the third while loop. So in `if (currentTime - prevTime > intervals){` the variable `currentTime` is always the original value of `currentTime` that was set at the top of the mode 3 while loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. It fixed the code, but I'm in shock how did that fixed the code. Especially the second loop. But nevertheless thank you very much I'm just glad it works :DDD